# RF frequency versus transmission efficiency

Tags: rf, wireless, frequency, high-frequency

Assuming all other variables are the same (modulation type, transmit duty cycle, receive sensitivity, data rate, etc), what is the relationship of RF frequency, range, and power consumption?  The dataset is any frequency between 300MHz and 5Ghz, and assume low data rate (<50kbps).

Is there a frequency range that is superior to other ranges in terms of range and power consumption?

I assume lower might be a little better.

What RF frequency is best for maximum range (assuming same transmit power is used)?  I also assume lower might be better here to a degree (i.e. comparing 5 Ghz to 2.4 Ghz), but I am not certain.

Is there data available that shows how well certain frequencies propagate through different materials (trees, buildings, etc)?

Comment: Is this related to your earlier question of a few days ago: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/279806/what-is-the-most-efficient-rf-solution-for-10-meter-datalink ?

Comment: @Andyaka, it is related, but it is different question. This is more about determining the best frequency for various applications.

Comment: Other variables are legislation permitting the bands you can use, legislation permitting the power you can use, legislation permitting the duty cycle of usage, the occupancy density of other users/interferers, the terrain effects versus frequency, the added complexity needed by higher frequency receivers to make best use of the signal bandwidth, the desired antenna size, the range required (desired range can affect frequency choice), and possibly other things that aren't springing to mind. All these factors make any reasonable answer "too broad" so I'm voting to close.

Comment: Legislation meaning within the USA? This question is applicable throughout the world. Certain areas around the globe are much less restrictive, if any at all. This is a question on the theory of RF signal propagation and power consumption.

Comment: Your question mentions power consumption as a constraint yet there is nothing in your accepted answer that factors this in so, in reality, what is your question. Neither is there anything in the answer about RF propagation versus operating frequency. Your question and accepted answer are some distance apart.

Comment: Higher transmission efficiency translates to less power consumption (typically, neglecting RF front end differences, mixing, and baseband processing).

Comment: I don't know how you have figured you get higher transmissions efficiency from any answer including any analysis of antenna fundamentals or the laws of physics. You are mistaken in your belief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Friis Transmission Loss.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare apples and oranges.

Making certain variables the same makes for an unfair comparison. At 1 MHz transmitting a signal with a bandwidth of 100 kHz takes up a lot of frequency space but does not allow for a high very datarate.

At 5 GHz the situation is quite different, the bandwidth can be a couple of MHz allowing for high many channels all with high datarates.

Also that 1 MHz will have a long range so you can only have very few transmitters.

For 1 MHz you need a very large antenna, this is impractical in a laptop for example.

There is no simple answer to your question because each frequency range has its own applications. There is no "best" in that respect.

Read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_spectrum) for an overview of usage of the radio spectrum.

Comment: I clarified the question to state between 300MHz and 5GHz, and also stated the same data rate.  If 300MHz is limited by a certain data rate, then assume that data rate across the frequency spectrum for comparison.

Comment: The only thing I'm going to assume after your remark is that you still do not seem to "get it". There is no "best". Forget about trying to find it.

Comment: I think I have the answer after the post about the Friis Transmission Loss equation. Basically, it shows that theoretically lower frequency is generally more efficient, but it comes at the cost of less bandwidth.The other impacts to this other variables which were not asked about such as the signal degradation going through materials, which may differ depending on frequency and material.

Comment: http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002478.html  This book discusses this in detail, including the description of the Friis equation and RF wave propagation across frequencies, and bandwidth considerations.